# Why hyperlinks are not simply called links in HTML?

Tags: html, http, hyperlink, w3c

The prefix **hyper** is used in HTTP (Hypertext Transfer Protocol) and in HTML (HyperText Markup Language). Links in a hypertext document are also called hyperlinks. I get that hyper means higher or more that something and that HTML is more that just a text file conceptually. I know also that this is Tim berners-Lee who used this word from Ted Nelson.

I would like to know why the hyper prefix is used, especially for links in HTML. Is there a technical reason that I don't get or is it just a semantical reason ? Does someone have a clear explanation of the usage of this term in this context ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first mention I can find is in the HTML 2.0 specification. Prior to that the docs all refer to just "links". There's no explanation of the change though. The 2.0 spec does describe hyperlinks in some detail, and speculating, the purpose may have been to indicate a particular _kind_ of link - one that is directed from a tail to a head, with a closed set of mark-up locations at the tail, and a resource at the head identified by a URI. "Hyperlink" would then just be a contraction of "Hypertext link".

Answer (score 0):

[From the W3C](https://www.w3.org/WhatIs.html)

> Ted Nelson originally invented the word "hypertext" for
> "non-sequential writing".
>
> What is HyperText?
>
> Hypertext is text which is not constrained to be linear. Hypertext is
> text which contains links to other texts. The term was coined by Ted
> Nelson around 1965 (see History ).
>
> HyperMedia is a term used for hypertext which is not constrained to be
> text: it can include graphics, video and sound , for example.
> Apparently Ted Nelson was the first to use this term too.
>
> Hypertext and HyperMedia are concepts, not products.

So it only follows on that "hyperlinks" would follow on that way.